# SQL Server : Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm getting this error

> msg 8115, level 16, state 2, line 18
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

with this SQL query

```
DECLARE @year VARCHAR(4);                       
DECLARE @month VARCHAR(2);                      

-- START OF CONFIGURATION SECTION                       
-- THIS IS THE ONLY SECTION THAT SHOULD BE MODIFIED                     
-- SET THE YEAR AND MONTH PARAMETERS                        

SET @year = '2013';                     
SET @month = '3';  -- 1 = January.... 12 = Decemeber.                       

-- END OF CONFIGURATION SECTION                     

DECLARE @startDate DATE                     
DECLARE @endDate DATE                       
SET @startDate = @year + '-' + @month + '-01 00:00:00';                     
SET @endDate = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @startDate);                       

SELECT                          
    DATEPART(YEAR, dateTimeStamp) AS [Year]                         
    , DATEPART(MONTH, dateTimeStamp) AS [Month]                         
    , COUNT(*) AS NumStreams                        
    , [platform] AS [Platform]                      
    , deliverableName AS [Deliverable Name]                     
    , SUM(billableDuration) AS NumSecondsDelivered                      
FROM                            
    DeliveryTransactions                        
WHERE                           
    dateTimeStamp >= @startDate                     
AND dateTimeStamp < @endDate                        
GROUP BY                            
    DATEPART(YEAR, dateTimeStamp)                       
    , DATEPART(MONTH, dateTimeStamp)                        
    , [platform]                        
    , deliverableName                       
ORDER BY                            
    [platform]                      
    , DATEPART(YEAR, dateTimeStamp)                         
    , DATEPART(MONTH, dateTimeStamp)                        
    , deliverableName
```

Comment: please can you point out which number is too large for data type? thanks

Comment: For dates as string, you should always use the **ISO-8601** format - `YYYYMMDD` - only this format is guaranteed to work for **any** language and/or regional settings

Comment: this works SET @month = '2';  -- 1 = January.... 12 = Decemeber.

Comment: how do i resolve this?

Comment: @marc_s, can we say the same about YYYY-MM-DD? Because I am using this format in all of my projects. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Anar: if you use `YYYY-MM-DD` for a `DATE` datatype - you're safe. For `DATETIME` however, it is **NOT SAFE** -- don't use it that way! Use `YYYYMMDD` only (**no** dashes!). To demonstrate, run this little snippet of code in SQL Server Mgmt Studio: `SET LANGUAGE german; SELECT CAST('2013-11-25' AS DATETIME)` - and you'll get a German error message telling you it cannot convert the string to a `DATETIME`. `SELECT CAST('20131125' AS DATETIME)` (**without** dashes!) works just fine.

Comment: Wow, this is really helpful, thanks for that. I am following your input on most SQL related questons, so keep it coming.

Answer (score 138):

Is the problem with `SUM(billableDuration)`? To find out, try commenting out that line and see if it works.

It could be that the sum is exceeding the maximum `int`. If so, try replacing it with `SUM(CAST(billableDuration AS BIGINT))`.

Comment: This `CAST(`  works perfectly with me, thanks

Comment: Yep, the combination ofcount_big and sum(cast(size as bigint)) worked like a charm.

Answer (score 32):

Very simple:

```sql
Use COUNT_BIG(*) AS NumStreams
```

Comment: This was a bit unexpected. Worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

Change `SUM(billableDuration) AS NumSecondsDelivered` to

`sum(cast(billableDuration as bigint))` 
or

`sum(cast(billableDuration as numeric(12, 0)))` according to your need.

The resultant type of of Sum expression is the same as the data type used. It throws error at time of overflow. So casting the column to larger capacity data type and then using Sum operation works fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT                          
    DATEPART(YEAR, dateTimeStamp) AS [Year]                         
    , DATEPART(MONTH, dateTimeStamp) AS [Month]                         
    , COUNT(*) AS NumStreams                        
    , [platform] AS [Platform]                      
    , deliverableName AS [Deliverable Name]                     
    , SUM(billableDuration) AS NumSecondsDelivered
```

Assuming that your quoted text is the exact text, one of these columns can't do the mathematical calculations that you want.  Double click on the error and it will highlight the line that's causing the problems (if it's different than what's posted, it may not be up there); I tested your code with the variables and there was no problem, meaning that one of these columns (which we don't know more specific information about) is creating this error.

One of your expressions needs to be casted/converted to an int in order for this to go through, which is the meaning of `Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int`.

Answer (score 1):

On my side, this error came from the data type "INT' in the Null values column.
The error is resolved by just changing the data a type to varchar.

Comment: Can you please show some code, thought that might be helpful.

Answer (score -6):

```
declare @d real
set @d=1.0;
select @d*40000*(192+2)*20000+150000
```

Comment: could you please add some explanation to your answer?