# Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int in sum case statement

Tags: sql-server, sum, case

I am getting this error in SQL Server:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

when running this query:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN t.type = 'doc' THEN t.id ELSE 0 END) AS DocType,
SUM(CASE WHEN t.type = 'pdf' THEN t.id ELSE 0 END) AS PdfType
```

Type is `varchar` and `id` is `int`.

I tried with `SUM(CASE WHEN t.type = 'doc' THEN ISNULL(t.id, 0) ELSE 0 END) AS DocType`

but that's not working.

What am I missing ?

Comment: `SUM` returns the data type of the input expression, which in this case appears to be a `int`. perhaps the sum of your column `ID` (seems odd you're summing the value of your ID's) is greater than 2,147,483,647. Try `CASE WHEN t.type='doc' THEN CONVERT(bigint,t.id) ELSE 0 END` Does that work?

Comment: As @Larnu said, it seems odd that you're summing Id values, especially as you're aliasing the result of the sum to `DocType` and `PdfType` - What's logic behind your query? Are you trying count the number of records of type Doc and Pdf?

Comment: Maybe what you really want is `COUNT`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server : Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15950580/sql-server-arithmetic-overflow-error-converting-expression-to-data-type-int)